# How can I vertically align the 'main' tree branch?

Tags: svg, d3.js, tree

I am trying to use the d3 tree layout to display a structure with a 'main' branch and few smaller branches. I would like the nodes in the main branch to vertically align with each other, either on the hard left or as a central column. **How can I do this?**

I use number of descendants to identify the main branch and have so far tried sorting by it which gives the following:

Sorting descending
[image: Sorting descending]
Sorting with median = max value
[image: Sorting with median = max value]

I've tried manually calculating x coordinates but always end up with overlapping nodes:

[image]

My code is pretty much identical to the example code for generating tree graphs with other clutter. If example code is needed I'll provide it but I don't think it would help.

Comment: I am also interested in better ways to display the data if anyone has some thoughts. It's a dependency graph.

Comment: The tree layout doesn't support this at all unfortunately, you'd have to modify the source.